# Unable to get command output when using pscustomobject in ForEach

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying the get the service status from a list of services. I am capturing the results in a pscustomobject for each of the service from the list.

```
$PCServices = @("AJRouter",
"ALG",
"bthserv",
"CertPropSvc",
"Dnscache",
"MapsBroker",
"lfsvc",
"HomeGroupListener",
"HomeGroupProvider",
"vmickvpexchange",
"vmicguestinterface",
"vmicshutdown",
"vmicheartbeat",
"vmicrdv",
"vmictimesync",
"vmicvss",
"SharedAccess",
"iphlpsvc");    
Write-Host "Checking PC Service Status"
    try
    {
        $PCServiceDetails = ForEach($PCSvc in $PCServices)
        {
            Get-Service -Name $PCSvc -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "$($_.DisplayName) : ($($_.Name))  $($_.Status) : Startup Type : $($_.StartType)"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Unable to get service details: $($PCServiceDetails.Name)/$($PCServiceDetails.DisplayName) : $($_.Exception)"
    }
```

I am not getting the desired out for the below line from the above code:

```
Write-Host "$($_.DisplayName) : ($($_.Name))  $($_.Status) : Startup Type : $($_.StartType)"
```

I don't want the above line to go into $PCServiceDetails. Output that I am getting is:

```
 : ()   : Startup Type : 
 : ()   : Startup Type : 
 : ()   : Startup Type :
```

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: you have NOT sent the output of the `Get-Service` to the `Write-Host` call. [*grin*] try adding a `|` after that line ...

Comment: Getting Error: rvice -Name $PCSvc -ErrorAction Stop | Write-Host "$($_.DisplayName)" Write-Host : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the 
parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: Pipeline object cannot be passed to a `write-host` or `write-output` like this. There has to be valid lineage. I will post the answer shortly.

Comment: But this logic is a little bit wrong. You should use two try/catch  block so that in case one service fails also, it should proceed with others... Let me repost the entire thing for you

Comment: @RajivIyer - that is because i forgot that `Write-Host` does NOT accept pipeline input. [*blush*]  please take a look at my answer for a version of your code that seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as RanadipDutta pointed out, `Write-Host` doesn't accept pipeline input. i forgot that. [*blush*]

here is my take on your problem. it puts the `try/catch` where it should be - around each call to `Get-Service` instead of around the whole loop.

```
$PC_ServiceList = @(
    'bits'
    'spooler'
    'w32time'
    'zzz_This_Better_Not_Be_There'
    )

Write-Host 'Checking PC Service Status ...'
Write-Host ''
$PC_ServiceDetails = ForEach ($PCSL_Item in $PC_ServiceList)
    {
    try
        {
        $ServiceInfo = Get-Service -Name $PCSL_Item -ErrorAction Stop

        Write-Host ('{0} : {1}  {2} : Startup Type : {3}' -f $ServiceInfo.DisplayName,
            $ServiceInfo.Name, $ServiceInfo.Status, $ServiceInfo.StartType)

        $ServiceInfo
        }
        catch
        {
        Write-Host ''
        Write-Host ('Unable to get service details: {0} : {1}' -f $PCSL_Item, $_)
        }
    }

$PC_ServiceDetails
```

output ...

```
Checking PC Service Status ...

Background Intelligent Transfer Service : bits  Running : Startup Type : Manual
Print Spooler : spooler  Running : Startup Type : Automatic
Windows Time : w32time  Stopped : Startup Type : Manual

Unable to get service details: zzz_This_Better_Not_Be_There : Cannot find any service with service name 'zzz_This_B
etter_Not_Be_There'.

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  bits               Background Intelligent Transfer Ser...
Running  spooler            Print Spooler
Stopped  w32time            Windows Time
```

Comment: Thanks, your method of Write-Host ('{0} : {1}  {2} : Startup Type : {3}' -f  is different. This is something like C#. Can you guide me to the documentation and what is -f switch?

Comment: @RajivIyer - you are most welcome! that `-f` thing is the "string format operator". [*grin*] this >>> -f Format operator - PowerShell - SS64.com — https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

Comment: @RajivIyer - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a pipeline object to `Write-Host` or `write-output` like that.

Here is the complete logic for the double try/catch so that it will not terminte in case one service fails; along with the issue that you are facing on the pipeline.

```
try
{
$PCServices = @("AJRouter",
"ALG",
"bthserv",
"CertPropSvc",
"Dnscache",
"MapsBroker",
"lfsvc",
"HomeGroupListener",
"HomeGroupProvider",
"vmickvpexchange",
"vmicguestinterface",
"vmicshutdown",
"vmicheartbeat",
"vmicrdv",
"vmictimesync",
"vmicvss",
"SharedAccess",
"iphlpsvc");    
Write-Host "Checking PC Service Status"

        $PCServiceDetails = ForEach($PCSvc in $PCServices)
        {
            try
            {
                $service = Get-Service -Name $PCSvc -ErrorAction Stop
                Write-Host "$($service.DisplayName) : ($($service.Name))  $($service.Status) : Startup Type : $($service.StartType)"
            }
            catch
            {
            "Issue in fetching information for the service: $PCSvc"
            $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }
}
catch
{
 Write-Host "Unable to get service details: $($PCServiceDetails.Name)/$($PCServiceDetails.DisplayName) : $($_.Exception)"
}
```

Hope it helps.